# using Badge with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm working on an addons into Firefox and I have some diffulty.

It is a little bit different to real JS and I have a problems.

What I want to do:

1. Grab all JS error with addEventListener and using Badge to count this.
2. Extra: maybe click button to list-it.

What I can do:

1. Make addEventListener into an **external script** using "pageMod"
2. Put button into the toolbar with badge **Index.js**
3. Changing Badge manually

What I'm not able to do:

1. Passing the External script the counter to button/badge value

[index.js] (start JS)

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "error_js",
  label: "Error JS",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  badge: 0,
  badgeColor: "#00AAAA",
  onClick: handleClick
});

function handleClick(state) {
  return; //display error into a box
}

button.badge = 10; //manually change badge

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptFile: "./error_log.js", //external JS
  contentScriptWhen: "start"
});
```

[error_log.js] (external js)

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var error_count = 0;
    var ff_js_error = {};
    ff_js_error.get = {
        setup: function () {
            console.log("setup");
            window.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
                this.error_count += 1;
                console.log(this.error_count);  //error_count undefined
                this.show_status(); // not going
                console.log("_trackEvent JavaScript Error: " + e.message + "\n " + e.filename + ": " + e.lineno);
            });
    },
    show_status: function() {
        // CHANGE BADGE
        console.log("show_status = " + this.error_count); //error count undefined
    }
}
ff_js_error.get.setup();
});
```

Comment: Can you make your content script port emit to your main.js/index.js which will increment the button.badge?

Comment: I can't do addEventListener in index.js because he did'nt know what is window. Im trying to change badge when i passed into the show_status()

Comment: No but you have a contentScript, and you spawn that from your index.js right? So before you spawn it you can set up a port listener, and then from your contentScript you can send messages to that port, are you familiar with this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port#port.emit%28%29

Comment: ho.. I see.. thanks for this tips, I'll try it this morning. Thanks for your time @Noitidart!

Comment: Keep up the great work :)